# Post dropbox selected values numerical id -codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter and its developing. I have used html dropbox inside the form. when I press the submit button I want to retrive and post id of selected drop box index value. How do I do that? please find the code I used.

```
<?php
echo form_open('homepage/askquestionview');

?><div class="form-group">


                <select name="cat" id="cato" onchange="activate_match()">
<?php
foreach ($catogories as $cat) {
    echo'<option value="' . $cat . '" id="cato" >' . $cat . '</option>';
}
?>

                </select>

            <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Post Your Question" id="postQuestion">
        </p>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

homepage/askquestionview function

```
public function askquestionview() {

           $data = array(

       'Student_Email' => $this->input->post('cato'),     

            );
            var_dump($data);
        }
```

output

```
array(1) { ["Student_Email"]=> bool(false) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select input name is 'cat' not 'cato'

```
<select name="cat"
```

Try a var_dump on $this->input->post() :

```
public function askquestionview() {
   var_dump(this->input->post());
}
```

Tips, use form_helper to create your input : form_dropdown()

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the data structure of codeigniter, but you'll probably have to modifiy for loop like this:

```
foreach ($catogories as $id => $cat) {
    echo'<option value="' . $id . '" id="cato" >' . $cat . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: As I said before, I don't know a lot about codeignitor. But if you have an array with the ID (as the numerical key) and the value, you can use my modified code.